# Generate image from dynamically created html from controller to view side, HOW?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I Have a page where i am getting dynamically generated html part.

```
$viewData['html'] = '<div class="row martop26"><div class="col-xs-12 co.... </div>';
$this->load->view('advertise/advertise_preview',$viewData);
```

This "Advertise_preview" is a html page where i get that html part separately.

$viewData['html'] is huge html portion. almost like an another page which is stored in a variable.

Now what i want to do with is that i want to convert that html portion on client side into image and without storing it into the data base, i want to show that generated image in a box.

On that box, i am applying  **jquery.zoom.js** to zoom the image on hover.

I have already used **html2canvas**. that doesn't suffice my requirement.

The problems with **html2canvas** are below:

1. I have to hide html part that i want to have screenshot of. where **html2canvas** doesn't accept hidden part to convert it to canvas
2. Second problem is that it generate image with either with black background or transparent.

If above both problem are solved then my work is done there.
Else, please suggest me some other JS or any other conversion idea.

My code for converting from html to canvas is below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var hello = $("#none"); // Whole html part in hello variable
html2canvas(hello, {
      onrendered: function(canvas) {
        // hello.hide();            
        // document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        // var cc = canvas.getImageData();
        // var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
        /*var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.fillRect(50,50,50,50);*/

        var img = new Image();
        img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
        // document.body.appendChild(img);
        // var jpegUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        // console.log(jpegUrl);

        $("#zoom").children().attr({
            src: img.src
        });
        $('.zoom').zoom();
      }
    });
});
```

You guys have always been helpful to me.
So Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you considered wkhtmltoimage : http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ ?

Comment: I haven't tried it but it seems from its site that it only help to make pdf out of html.
Not image.
And if i merge that method with another method to make image out of pdf then i will take way more time to get my result.

Comment: You can render images too . Quote : `wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage are open source (LGPL) command line tools to render HTML into PDF **and various image formats**`. I used it to render pdf from my views and it woked pretty well.

Comment: Ok let me try and i will reply back as soon as possible.

But for that i have install that library on my server and then i have to restart the sever.

I will try that  and update my feedback.

Comment: I am not sure how busy your website is but if you do this every time the page/image is viewed then you will potentially see some increased page load times.